How to Automate OTP Retrieval and Passing for a Python Automation Bot?
I am working on an automation bot in Python. In the initial phase, my bot logs into a website. However, every time it logs in, the website requires a one-time password (OTP) sent to a phone number. I want to automate this process so that the bot retrieves the OTP automatically and uses it for login.
The issue is that I can only register accounts using a phone number, and the OTP is sent to that number via SMS.
I attempted to use Twilio to manage the phone number and receive the OTPs programmatically. My expectation was that Twilio would capture all SMS messages sent to the virtual phone number, including OTP messages from the website. I planned to retrieve these OTPs via the Twilio API and pass them to the automation bot for login.
What I Expected:
I expected Twilio to deliver all incoming messages, including OTPs, to my account so I could fetch them automatically using the API. This would have streamlined the process, but unfortunately, Twilio seems to filter OTP messages and does not provide them, making this approach ineffective.
Now, I am looking for alternative solutions to fetch OTPs from a physical phone number and integrate them into my automation workflow.
Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Organisations around the world are moving away from one-time passwords over SMS to close precisely this loophole. It seems that Twilio have already moved to close it. You haven't said what you're trying to automate, but many sites that offer data on the web also provide an API. You might do better exploring that option.
